# professional way to update images in a listview in own thread

Tags: android, multithreading, image, imageview

What is an professional way to update ImageViews in a ListView like WhatsApp does? How could I realize that? Seems like the update and download sequence of the Images needs to run in it's own thread, but in which kind of thread so I don't get in trouble by changing the UI-Thread?

Comment: You nay want to be clearer on exactly what you want.  "Like what's app" isn't a good description-  odds are good that half of the answerers here don't use the app, and who knows what version of the app we may have used (which may have totally different behavior).

Comment: That's a good point. Thanks. It is a general issue independend to the version. It's about updating ImageViews in a ListView. If I got 3 Tabs, change from one to the other I want the ListView Tab to get updated after getting back to it.

Comment: You could directly load pictures from a server. If you replace one, it would load it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asynchronous image loading, I'd highly recommend [aquery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading).

The simplest way to load an image without concerning about which thread will take care of it, looks something like.-

```
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Regarding `ListView`s, you should take a look at `Delay Image Loading` section as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Library. Its the best image loader library from my experience. Very easy to use & most importantly performs optimized in the listview.-
**Specially for handling ImageView recycling and download cancellation in an adapter**
Example from their site-

Adapter re-use is automatically detected and the previous download canceled.

```
@Override
public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
  if (view == null) {
    view = new SquaredImageView(context);
  }
  String url = getItem(position);

  Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);
}
```